# Trac ticket-custom permission

Tags: trac

Привет, я создал дополнительное поле checkbox в trac, как описано [здесь](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTicketsCustomFields) 
Как сделать что бы это поле было доступно только для для пользователей состоящих в группе TRAC_ADMIN ?